# Has R fluency overtaken SAS in terms of being more popular as a hiring requirement?

Tags: r, sas, careers

Seems like when I first graduated (was a while ago, life went in a different direction and I wasn't an analyst for long), almost all the job listings wanted SAS? While R had only got limited traction outside academia, as it was still relatively young.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! This question might not be quite on topic here, but I will give a brief comment and say that Python appears to be preferred over both R and SAS.

Comment: In Silicon Valley and the SF Bay Area, R (and/or Python) are mandatory for most jobs in tech development. SAS is still used in pharma because federal regulators often prefer of require it. (SAS output has dates of creation and viewed as somewhat secure against tampering.) // For a couple of decades, I have used R teaching many  statistics grad courses; many students have said that this relatively limited acquaintance with R for stat analysis has been an advantage in getting hired. // My info on the importance of SAS is less direct. // Ability to link among different software is in high demand.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the positions I have seen advertised in searches for statistical jobs, yes, fluency in R (or Python) is now more valuable as a job skill than fluency in SAS.  However, there are certainly still many positions where fluency in SAS is desirable or even required.  Most large organisations that employ a data analytics team will have staff specialising in a range of languages, and some aim to be able to have a skill base that can cover all the major statistical languages.

There are still quite a few analysis jobs in government and large corporations that use SAS as the primary language.  For some of these institutions, they started using SAS in the 1980s (or even the late 1970s), and so they have a lot of existing code in this language.  As a rule, the longer an institution has been doing large-scale data analysis, the more likely it is that they have substantial amounts of coding (and ongoing need for) SAS.

I expect that SAS coding will remain valuable, but (at the time of writing) the majority of positions that specify statistical languages now specify R.